# AWS SNS - How to get subscriber lambda triggered by publisher lambda output

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have a lambda function which sends mail and returns the `MessageID` as output if the email was sent successfully, error message if it fails. Now I want to create an architecture where this returned email status will be saved in an SNS topic. There will be another Lambda function as subscriber which will be triggered by the Email status of the SNS topic.

Example: If the publisher Lambda returns *MessageID*, the subscriber Lambda will return *"yes"*, *"no"* for *error message*. Is it possible to achieve? If not, what is the closest can I go?

**What I have done so far**

1. Created an SNS Topic
2. Created a subscriber Lambda function for the topic. Added trigger for the following SNS topic in the Lambda.
3. Added SNS client in my existing Lambda which I want to use as publisher. This Lambda returns the MessageID if mail is sent successfully.
4. I published a simple message to the specified SNS topic.

Here is code of *subscriber function* following the docs :

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    return {
        # 'statusCode': 200,
        # 'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
         message = json.loads(event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']) 
         print("JSON: " + json.dumps(message)) 
         return message
    }
```

My code for *publishing message to SNS topic*:

```
sns_client = boto3.client('sns', aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_KEY, region_name=AWS_REGION)

sns_response = sns_client.publish(
        TopicArn='my-ARN',    
        Message='Hello World',    
    )
```

Comment: the architecture seems correct.  What is the problem you're facing ?  Any error message to share ?

Comment: @SébastienStormacq when I run my publisher code, it shows the sns_response. But I don't see any message in my sns or any log in my cloudwatch. Stuck down here

Comment: Can you update the question with the above to make it clear what you are asking for ?  Also, can you share the cloudformation template or CDK code you are using to create that infra.  It will help to replicate

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your issue but could not.  I used Javascript and Typescript but this should not be your problem.

Here is a CDK code to create your infrastructure  :

```js
import cdk = require('@aws-cdk/core');

import sns = require('@aws-cdk/aws-sns');
import subs = require('@aws-cdk/aws-sns-subscriptions');

import lambda = require('@aws-cdk/aws-lambda');

export class CdkStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    let fn = new lambda.Function(this, 'SODemoFunction', {
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_10_X,
      code: lambda.Code.asset('./src'),
      handler: 'index.handler'
    });

    const topic = new sns.Topic(this, 'SODemoTopic', {
      displayName: 'StackOverflow Demo'
    });
    topic.addSubscription(new subs.LambdaSubscription(fn));

  }
}
```

Here is the JS for the Lambda funtion

```
exports.handler =  async function(event, context) {
    console.log("EVENT: \n" + JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
    return event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']; 
}
```

Here is how I am sending the message :

```sh
$ aws sns publish --topic-arn arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:012345678912:CdkStack-SODemoTopicD9C6180 --message "hello world"
{
    "MessageId": "b73b0141-e7d1-50f0-93ae-54f44cf8bb78"
}
```

and here is what I see in cloudwatch log

```
2019-07-27T01:29:13.981Z cc56486b-0a8f-4e7a-a880-1e09d7631b98 INFO EVENT:
{
    "Records": [
        {
            "EventSource": "aws:sns",
            "EventVersion": "1.0",
            "EventSubscriptionArn": "arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:012345678912:CdkStack-SODemoTopicD9C61805:22d228db-9c3c-488d-84a3-cbdbf5e9d112",
            "Sns": {
                "Type": "Notification",
                "MessageId": "b73b0141-e7d1-50f0-93ae-54f44cf8bb78",
                "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:012345678912:CdkStack-SODemoTopicD9C61805",
                "Subject": null,
                "Message": "hello world",
                "Timestamp": "2019-07-27T01:29:13.862Z",
                "SignatureVersion": "1",
                "Signature": "Xqy8DYPWu+ZFw0hU23C78CTuFB3DblDSrY+vY44sDFMLmuZjM/kaQNvTmHGlLEFcdG3MBQQYWtMc/VQjVXONeIuJr4S336IENPTWylwSNSKHi5kAD93EmDiLl2y3jW2CdsDN9/QwQ5aJQrIkIp91VnWmCx03kUqgzhMdvQ0bsz64EUN6vMpKDZ4oJ6Ug0zTPUwyvcEneMzYkaFISakZZr1SHZYfHp7bfqZVyc2fjOIHhFIyePbMOsGYpQC8CGgD8d2Yekv0f1wYQKn5At4aHWQ29ObyjdsnbYCwlAuej47n1qVwh9li7XKFsRqyqE562Ul7OdLwA1t8tZdYbYh6zjA==",
                "SigningCertUrl": "https://sns.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-6aad65c2f9911b05cd53efda11f913f9.pem",
                "UnsubscribeUrl": "https://sns.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:012345678912:CdkStack-SODemoTopicD9C61805:22d228db-9c3c-488d-84a3-cbdbf5e9d112",
                "MessageAttributes": {}
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Can you try on your side ?
CDK Doc is here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/getting_started.html